# Excel create graph for bought domain names

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a excel table with 450 domain names and I have a column for the "created on" which I would want to manipulate to create an history graph but I really don't knwo how to handle it.  I'm new to pivot tables, but I already change my data from range to table.

I would want to have a graph having the years on the x-axis and having the added number of domains bought on the y-axis and be able to see the "curve".

Could somebody give me some advice on how to create that only with pivot table configuration?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to pack it all into one picture for you.  If the dates are stored as dates, the Pivot Table can "Group Field" by Years.  This will summarize the data in groups.  You can then create a Pivot Chart with this summarized data.  Most common issue when doing this is not having all the dates formatted correctly.

[image: Pivot Table and Chart overview]

**Edit**

To get from here to a cumulative total, you can change the Pivot Table "Show Values As" to "Running Total In...".  Select the `DATE` field when you get the prompt.

Change the display option.

[image: menu]

Chart is now cumulative.  (My pictures are now the same since I regenerated the data and added a couple years to show it.)

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for your screenshot.  It sounds really great but I would want kind of a curve that grows from 0 (first date I bought a domain [1995/05] to my 450th in the last month I bought a domain [2015/04].  The graph that your procedure gives is not adding all new domains, instead it "starts" from 0 each year, but I would want an addition.  Ask me if you need clearer info! ;)

Comment: Yes.  Change the "Show Values As" (from right clicking on Pivot Tabel) to "Running Total In...".  When prompted, select `DATE` (or whatever your date field is called).  You will then get a running total or a cumulative count which it sounds like what you want.  I'll edit another screenshot in.

Comment: Thanks a lot Byron.  It's everything I wanted and I thank you for teaching me those right-clicking possibilities!